# ignore setup mock for one file

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a decorator that I use on a lot of my methods. To not have to mock it each time, I have added a mock on `jest.setup.js`:

```js
jest.mock('src/something', () => {
  someMethod: jest.fn.mockImplementation(/*some implementation*/)
})
```

This works fine, but now I want to unit test this one method (the `someMethod` in this example) and I can't, since it brings up the mock. How can I ignore this mock for only this file/test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jest.unmock(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestunmockmodulename) in the test file of a module. So that your module under test will use the real module rather than the mocked version.

Let's see an example:

`./src/stackoverflow/73129547/something.ts`:

```
export const someMethod = () => 1;
```

This is the module we want to mock.

`./jest.setup.js`:

```js
jest.setTimeout(5 * 1000);

jest.mock('./stackoverflow/73129547/something', () => ({
  someMethod: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(0),
}));
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
};
```

We set up the mock using `jest.mock()` in the `jest.setup.js` file. So that every module under test will use the mocked version of this module.

Suppose our project has two modules: `a.ts` and `b.ts`, they use the `someMethod` exported from the `something` module.

`./src/stackoverflow/73129547/a.ts`:

```
import { someMethod } from './something';
export const a = someMethod;
```

`./src/stackoverflow/73129547/b.ts`:

```
import { someMethod } from './something';
export const b = someMethod;
```

The test suites of `a` and `b` modules:

`./src/stackoverflow/73129547/a.test.ts`:

```
import { a } from './a';

describe('73129547 - a', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(a()).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

`./src/stackoverflow/73129547/b.test.ts`:

```
import { b } from "./b";

describe('73129547 - b', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(b()).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73129547/b.test.ts
 PASS  stackoverflow/73129547/a.test.ts (9.829 s)

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.681 s
```

As you can see the expected execution result. Both the `a` and `b` modules use the mocked `someMethod` which has a mock return value: `0`.

Now, we want to test the `someMethod` of the `something` module, we should test the real `someMethod` rather than the mocked one. Test mock implementations make no sense.

`./src/stackoverflow/73129547/something.test.ts`:

```
import { someMethod } from './something';

jest.unmock('./something');

describe('73129547 - something', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(someMethod()).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73129547/a.test.ts
 PASS  stackoverflow/73129547/b.test.ts
 PASS  stackoverflow/73129547/something.test.ts

Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.955 s, estimated 14 s
```

As you can see, the return value of real `someMethod` is `1`. `jest.unmock(moduleName)` will unmock the module and return the real module.